# What is the significance of II.9 in a Kingdom Hearts 3 scene?

Tags: kingdom-hearts-3

During one of the cut-scenes it shows Kingdom Hearts II.9

Is there a significance to this, or perhaps a chapter in the story?

I know Kingdom hearts is a complex story written over several games with history and back history and side history. So, wasn't sure if this was part of all that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As you said, Kingdom Hearts is a story that ranges over several games (and consoles).

The introductory chapter of Kingdom Hearts 3 is titled as 2.9 because it picks up where the ending to Kingdom Hearts 0.2: Birth by Sleep – A Fragmentary Passage in Kingdom Hearts 2.8 leaves off.

During the end cutscene of Kingdom Hearts 0.2: Birth by Sleep, as well at the beginning of Kingdom Hearts 3, we learn that

> Sora is stripped of his powers after being nearly consumed by Xehanort during the Mark of Mastery exam in Kingdom Hearts 3D: Dream Drop Distance

This chapter is designed to build the bridge between the events that occurred in Kingdom Hearts 3D: Dream Drop Distance and Kingdom Hearts 3 before sending Sora on his journey.

Comment: Interesting, thanks for your answer. It actually makes sense now due to the progression scenes in KH3 which show different titles